# How do I make a button console using Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have got a script wiht nine diferent options in a text menu. I would like to change the menu for a GUI using tkinter.

The menu has nine options which are a bucle if, elif... esle from 1 to 9. The last one is the 'exit' one.

How do I transform the menu if, elif, elif....else in a window with nine buttons each one for a different option and run the same script ?

I am trying the following code:

```
from tkinter import*
ventana = Tk()
variable = '' 
def opcion1():
    global variable
    variable = '1'def opcion2 ():
global variable
variable = '2'
root = Tk()
boton1 = Button(ventana, text='OPCION1',command=opcion1)
boton1.pack()

boton2 = Button(ventana, text='OPCION2',command=opcion2)
boton2.pack()

botonSalir = Button(ventana, text='EXIT',command=quit)
botonSalir.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hopefully this helps!

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def f1():
    print('f1')
def f2():
    print('f2')
def f3():
    print('f3')

MODES = [("Option1", f1, '1'), ("Option2", f2, '2'), ("Option3", f3, '3')]

v = StringVar()
v.set("L") # initialize

for text, function, mode in MODES:
    b = Radiobutton(root, text=text, indicatoron=0, variable=v, command=function, value=mode)
    b.pack(anchor=W)
root.mainloop()
```